# Why is my std::priority_queue with custom comparator ordering elements incorrectly?

Tags: c++, std

I was refreshing some algorithm knowledge and implementing djikstra in c++ and saw this seemingly broken behavior in `std::priority_queue`. Can anyone shed some light on why I might be seeing this?

I created a `priority_queue` with a custom comparator, to allow me to insert indices into the `priority_queue` and prioritize them based on the minimum values in another `vector dist`. There is no easy/cheap way to remove elements and reinsert them, so when a distance is updated, I'm just reinserting the index into the queue and will have multiple entries for it (which I can skip as I visit them later, if I've seen them already).

However, when I update a dist and reinsert the index it is not correctly ending up on top of the queue.

I've pasted a minimal repro below. Does anyone see anything that might be causing this? I am building this with clang 14.0.6 x86_64-pc-windows-msvc in VS Code.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int N = 9;
    
    // create d vector with INT_MAX, but last will be 0  
    vector<int> dist(N, INT_MAX);
    dist.back() = 0;

    // cmp for indices, so that index with lowest d element gets pri
    auto cmp = [&](int a, int b) { return dist[a] > dist[b]; };
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);

    // fill q with indices 0-(N-1), should be prioritized by d
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { q.push(i); }

    // start state seen in debugger
    // dist = {MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, 0}
    // q.c = {8, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3}

    // 8 is top index, since d[8] is 0, everything else is INT_MAX
    // This assert is passing
    assert(q.top() == 8);
    q.pop();

    // set d[0] to 0 and add another 0 entry to the queue
    // this should end on top, b/c d[0] == 0 and others are INT_MAX
    dist[0] = 0;
    q.push(0);

    // final state seen in debugger
    // dist = {0, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, MAX, 0}
    // q.c = {2, 0, 6, 0, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1}

    // THIS FAILS! because q.top() returns 2
    assert(q.top() == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure changing the state of the comparator after filling the priority_queue causes undefined behavior.  I think there was a cppcon video about this, let me see if I can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparison function is required to be a predicate. And a predicate is required to return the same answer for comparing `a` and `b`. *Always*, no matter what. So if you do something that changes the result of that answer, you get undefined behavior.

If you want to do this, then you're going to need to explicitly use a container (like `vector`) and re-sort it every time your sort criteria changes. `priority_queue` doesn't give you that power.

Comment: Wow, I guess that would do it then. (Though, I wonder what it is actually doing with those values, since caching seems a bit "extra" for a heap insert op). Thanks! There are some obvious alternatives I could use here, but this one definitely caught me off guard. :-)

Comment: @cwa76 there is no special thing about those value, it equals to performing standard heap insertion (add to end then move up). (note: the standard probably doesn't specify the algorithm used and the result can vary.)

Comment: @appleapple that's my assumption, but I'm still very confused why this actually fails. I understand that it is "undefined" but surely it isn't caching the predicate results, and if it is actually applying that predicate for each comparison why would it not sort correctly when the 0 index is added the second time?

Comment: @cwa76: "*I understand that it is "undefined"*" What more do you need to know than that? I mean sure, it might be interesting to look at a specific implementation to see what it's doing that causes this specific abnormality. But it won't get you any closer to making your code do what it needs to, will it?

Comment: @cwa76 my first standard means "the normal way", the second standard refers to the "c++ standard". There is no caching  happening, and it's the result of normal binary heap operation. I've add an answer to show the possible steps.

Comment: @NicolBolas I just wanted to understand more what is happening to make it actually fail.  apple is right, and this is obvious after looking at the graphic below; when the inserted 0 has to bubble-up through the previous 0 (as it incidentally does in this example) it hits a roadblock because 0 will not be greater than 0. If I change it to use a >= comparator, it fails with an assertion of strict weak ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Extend [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75583073/why-is-my-stdpriority-queue-with-custom-comparator-ordering-elements-incorrect/75583193?noredirect=1#comment133349659_75583193) into answer,

The sequence is the result of standard binary heap operation.

---

NOTE: the behavior is probably not specified by the c++ standard and should not be rely on.

---

---

#### 1. the initial sequence represent a binary heap  `{8, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3}`

(the color means it compare smaller than other nodes)

[image: initial tree]

---

#### 2. pop

- swap top item `8` with last item `3` and remove it
- move the item `3` down to maintain heap property

  - Here *your specific implementation*

    - move down when it equals to the child (possibly `if(!comp(node,child))`)
    - use the right tree when both child are equal
      [image: pop and maintain]

---

#### 3. push `0`  *with new comparator (state)*

- add `0` to the end
- move `0` up *with new comparator (state)*

  - swap with `1`
  - here *the specific implementation* find out it's equal to parent and stop moving up.
    [image: push and move up]

---

#### 4. you have the final sequence `{2, 0, 6, 0, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1}`

[image: final tree]

Comment: Ah, yeah, this makes a ton of sense. And bringing it all together, if I change the comparator to try to force the swap by using `dist[a] >= dist[b]` (ie `>=` instead of `>`) it fails explicitly due to requirement mentioned by @nicol-bolas in the other answer, in `_Debug_lt_pred`, described by a comment `test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering, when the arguments are the cv-same-type`.

Comment: @cwa76 well [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) is not equal to comparator consistency. Even you don't change the comparator (or it's state) at all, `<=` is still not a valid `Compare`.

Comment: @cwa76 And as showed in the post, it does move down `3` when they are equal, it can as well move up `0` too (and still keep heap property). (the specific implementation just doesn't do it.)